# >Some< pictures not showing in IE6

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-6

I am working on a website which needs to work across multiple browsers *unfortunately* also including IE6.

I am using the sliding doors technique for buttons which works beautifully in Chrome, Safari and FF but the images are completely invisible in IE6. What's even stranger is that it's not all the images, just the button backgrounds. The icons I put into the actual buttons render fine. Any idea why?

```
HTML:
    <a id="re" href="#" class="button"><span><span class="resolved">Mark as Resolved</span></span></a>


CSS:
  a.button
  {
   background:transparent url(images/normal_end.png) no-repeat scroll top right;
   display:block;
   float:left;
   height: 32px;
   padding:3px;
   padding-right: 5px;
   margin:4px;
   text-decoration:none;
   color:#555;
   font-weight:normal;
   width:100px;
   font-size: 15px;
  }
  a.button span 
  {
   background: url(images/normal.png) no-repeat;
   display:block !important;
   line-height:22px;
   padding:0 5px 0 5px;
  }
```

Comment: There's no question here. Even if one was asked, it would be impossible to answer without sample code.

Comment: I'd say it's pretty clear what the question was but I hope it's explicit enough for you now.

Comment: No, it's not pretty clear. The resolution you found is a well-known limitation, but from your question I wouldn't have even remotely guessed that could have been the problem. You know, actually mentioning you're trying to layer transparent PNGs over something else might have been a big help.

Comment: You know, I thought this service was about experienced programmers/users *helping* those who are just starting out. Not attacking them.

Comment: I downvoted (your question, not your answer) because *any* Google search such as "ie6 png" or "ie6 image problem" or "ie6 background not working" brings up the answer to your question. You didn't do basic research.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I must say since noticing that most google searches brought me here anyway I started searching here straight away and there wasn't a question like that. Clearly, that's the wrong practice but I assumed I wasn't the only one who does that and it would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE6 has a problem with png images, but you can put images as background of divs.

```
<body>  
<div class="imageyouneed"></div>  
</body>

<style>  
body {background-color:#000}  
div.imageyouneed {background:url(flower-transparent.png) no-repeat; height:100px;width:100px}  
</style>

<!--[if gte IE 5]>  
<style type="text/css">  
  div {  
  background:none;  
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='flower.png',sizingMethod='crop');  
  }  
</style>  
<![endif]-->
```

Please note that height and width are that of image.